# bootstarp d-flex align-Items-center off centers items to the left

Tags: html, flexbox, bootstrap-5

I was following a course on web development by Andrei neagoie. it was going well and I was enjoying the course. when I got to the bootstrap section (where Andrei was building a startup landing page) I encountered a problem. when I was centering the ex and button vertically using d-flex align-items-center h-100 it did center it vertically but also slightly off-centered it to the left.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Startup</title>
    
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- My own stylesheet -->
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container d-flex align-items-center h-100">
      <div class="row">
        <header class="text-center col-12">
          <h1 class="text-uppercase"><strong>The biggest startup event of the year</strong></h1>
        </header>
        <section class="text-center col-12">
          <hr>
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xl">Find out more</button>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have managed to find no documentation on this issue, so I don't know what to do. I've googled everything I could think of but nothing came up. it's almost like I'm the only one who has this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Add `justify-content-center`.

See the snippet below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Startup</title>

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- My own stylesheet -->
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
      <div class="row">
        <header class="text-center col-12">
          <h1 class="text-uppercase"><strong>The biggest startup event of the year</strong></h1>
        </header>
        <section class="text-center col-12">
          <hr>
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xl">Find out more</button>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```